# Source code in spring which takes in a JSON String(key-value Pair ) as an input and gives out the Updated JSON string

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need help in the coding of a program in spring which takes in a JSON String(key-value Pair ) as an input and gives out the Updated JSON string

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are asking in terms of REST, if yes then refer below snippet -

```
    @Controller
    public class JSONTest {

    // Below method will take iput as JSON
        @RequestMapping(value="/getData",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void consumeJson(@RequestBody String s) {
            System.out.println("json body : " + s);
        }

    // Below method will produce output as JSON
        @RequestMapping(value="/sendData",produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public String sendJson() {
         //Create jsonObject
         //do some things with jsonObject, put some header information in jsonObject
         return jsonObject.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have already on that, what am i suppose to write on that sendJson function?